# Behaviour of the equations $u_t = \Delta^3 u$ and $u_t = -\Delta^2 u$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In a paper I'm reading there's a reference to a 'S. D. Eidelman: Parabolic Systems (1969)' which seems to be out of print and impossible to get hold of.

In it, apparently, it is shown that for $u_t = -\Delta^2 u$, the similarity profile $b(x,t) = t^{-N/4}F(y), \,\, y=x/t^{1/4}$ is such that $|F(y)|<De^{-d|y|^{4/3}}$.

Does anyone know how this is derived, and how to get a similar estimate for the similarity profile of $u_t = \Delta^3 u$? Is there any other existing literature where I can find out more about this?

Many thanks.